# Marginal Distribution Calculation for use in Binomial Distribution.

Tags: binomial-distribution, marginal-distribution, multinomial-distribution

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHDIT.png)

In the question I know how to calculate marginal distribution for X1 and X2.

Like for X1 the marginal distribution for each column is the sum of each joint probability mass function in that column. For example the marginal distribution for 0 column of X1 = 0.343 But I'm not able to understand how to use marginal Probability of X1 and X2 in the binomial distribution as asked in the question in the image!

Comment: Don't post question as images.  Type it out and format it with MathJaX so search can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just summing the probability per row and column you get  your distribution

For example, as $X_1$ is concerned you get

$$P(X_1=3)=0.027=p^3$$

That is $p=\sqrt[3]{0.027}=0.3$

Which means $X_1\sim Bi(3;0.3)$

Similar reasoning for $X_2$

Comment: ThankYou so much Sir & so in the question Bi(3, ), 3 refers to n in X1 and X2 i.e. that row and column respectively.Therefore  X2 ~ Bi(3,0.1)

Comment: @AISHWINTIKKU : exactly

Comment: @AISHWINTIKKU : although you solved the problem here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4034235/find-the-varx-for-the-continuous-random-variables-with-given-joint-probability I answered suggesting you a different and, IMHO, interesting way. Get a look at my answer!

Comment: Thank You so much Sir for the help.